# Need little support in trimap generation for alpha masking

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to extract out hair from a portrait image. For this I have done following till now:

1. Convert the image into grayscale then to binary
2. Morphological operation to separate out the hair.
3. Find contours, sort it, top to bottom, draw the topmost contour only as mask (hair obviously).
4. Again perform some morphological operations to find out sure foreground and unknown area.

Now, when I combine sure foreground and unknown to make mask which I am going to use to alpha masking to extract hair, I got a unwanted black boundary line. 
So, how to combine two image without that boundary. 
Or, is there any other better way for trimap generation?

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2


img = cv2.imread("Test5.jpg")
image = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
# cv2.imshow("GrayScaled", image)
# cv2.waitKey(0)

ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(image, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
# cv2.imshow("Black&White", thresh)
# cv2.waitKey(0)


kernel1 = np.ones((2,2),np.uint8)
erosion = cv2.erode(thresh,kernel1,iterations=4)
# cv2.imshow("AfterErosion", erosion)
# cv2.waitKey(0)

kernel2 = np.ones((1,1),np.uint8)
dilation = cv2.dilate(erosion,kernel2,iterations = 5)
# cv2.imshow("AfterDilation", dilation)
# cv2.waitKey(0)

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(dilation, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

#sort contours
sorted_ctrs = sorted(contours, key=lambda ctr: cv2.boundingRect(ctr)[1])

mask = np.zeros_like(img) # Create mask where white is what we want, black otherwise
cv2.drawContours(mask, sorted_ctrs, 0, (255, 255, 255), -1) # Draw filled contour in mask
out = np.zeros_like(img) # Extract out the object and place into output image
out[mask == 255] = [255]

# Show the output image
cv2.imshow('Output', out)
cv2.waitKey(0)

image1 = cv2.cvtColor(out, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# noise removal
kernel = np.ones((10, 10), np.uint8)
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(image1, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel, iterations = 2)

# sure background area
sure_bg = cv2.dilate(opening, kernel, iterations=4)

# Finding sure foreground area
sure_fg = cv2.erode(opening, kernel, iterations=3)
cv2.imshow("foreground", sure_fg)
cv2.waitKey(0)

# Finding unknown region
sure_fg = np.uint8(sure_fg)
unknown = cv2.subtract(sure_bg, sure_fg)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(unknown, 240, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

unknown[thresh == 255] = 128

kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (5, 5))
unknown = cv2.erode(unknown, kernel, iterations=1)

cv2.imshow("unknown", unknown)
cv2.waitKey(0)

final_mask = sure_fg + unknown
cv2.imwrite("Trimap.jpg", final_mask)
cv2.imshow("final_mask", final_mask)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Here are my input and output image:

[image: Original Image]

[image: Trimap]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The black line between `unknown` and `sure_fg` is because the `unknown` is eroded at the end with the line

`unknown = cv2.erode(unknown, kernel, iterations=1)`

After removing that line, here's the mask created:

[image]